# Return array from text in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, text

I have one text element and button element. I write `12,34,679` to text element, then press to button. It must alert() the first item of the array, generated from text element. How can I do it? Thanks!

Comment: And what have you already done?

Comment: you can use javascript for this :-)

Comment: Can you show some code? I don't follow your question. If that is a string, you can get an array out of it with `myString.split(',')`

Comment: Thank you very much, guys, you all! I solved the problem, with the first answer of @JaredPar! Thank you! I did it with the way, which @JaredPar said, but I think I made a problem, so it didn't work. But know it works perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to create an array by splitting on commas you can do the following

```
var text = getTheText();
var array = text.split(',');
var first = array[0];
alert(first);
```

Comment: +1 for breaking it down into understandable steps for a beginner.

Comment: Thanks, @JaredPar! You wrote first, so, I will accept your answer! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Split) method.

```
<input type="text" id="textElement">12,34,679</input>

var text = document.getElementById('textElement');
var firstIndex = text.split(',')[0];
alert(firstIndex);
```

Answer (score 1):

very few informations
basically you should use split()
    example:

```
 text = htmlElement.text();
 textArray = text.split(',');
 firstElement = textArray[0];
```